# Combine/ dataframes across lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rbind

I am trying to merge like-named dataframes between two lists of dataframes using `rbind` or similar. The background is that a user is importing files containing data for 130 different compounds as a unique dataframes, so there's a list of 130 data frames within each data file imported. The data files are imported as a list, so there's a list of data files containing lists of dataframes.

The compounds/dataframe names remain constant day to day, but the number of files being imported is variable dependent on user preference.

I would like to `rbind` the dataframes together by compound. Here's a reproducible example that does what I want.

```
list.of.lists <- list(
        df.list1 <- list(df1 = data.frame("ID" = letters[1:10],
                                          "Data" = rnorm(10, 5, 2)),
                         df2 = data.frame("ID" = letters[1:10],
                                          "Data" = rnorm(10, 5, 2))
                         
        ),
        df.list2 <- list(df1 = data.frame("ID" = letters[11:20],
                                          "Data" = rnorm(10, 5, 2)),
                         df2 = data.frame("ID" = letters[11:20],
                                          "Data" = rnorm(10, 10, 2))
        )
)

j <- Map(rbind, list.of.lists[[1]], list.of.lists[[2]]) # Results in a list of data frames (df1, df2)
```

This generates a list of 2 data frames with 20 results in each, exactly what I want, but when applied to real-world, I don't know how many lists will be contained in the `list.of.lists`.

I suspect the answer is relatively straight forward, but I'm a little stuck. Help  is much appreciated!

Comment: `do.call(function(...) Map(rbind, ...), list.of.lists)`

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Keeps all the names of the dfs intact and everything. Remind me what the ellipse (...) syntax does in this case? Please make this as an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're looking for the function `do.call`:'

```r
lapply(list.of.lists, function(x){
  do.call(what = rbind, x)
})
```

Comment: This ends up losing the names of the "df"s. I can wrap it in a setNames() function, but would rather not if possible.